# Void function to swap two integers

Tags: c

The logic of my swap function works, but when I compile and run the program, it seems the void function does not take effect. Therefore, my numbers are not getting swapped because the void function is not working.

I am expecting the void function to work. I tried writing the logic in the main thread, and it works just fine. When I tried using a void function, I get no swapped integers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//prototype
void swap(int x, int y){
    int temp;
    temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}
int main(void){
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter X: \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("Enter Y: \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    swap(x,y);

    printf("%d , %d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are passed by value, i.e. a copy.

Comment: You shall use pointers.

Comment: @tkausl I don't think that sentence would make much sense to a beginner who doesn't already know that.

Comment: I see, I needed pointers to the variables.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the parameters `x` and `y` in the `swap` function are *completely separate* from the `x` and `y` local variables in the main function — they are stored in separate locations despite having the same names.

When you call `swap` with: `swap(x,y)`, you are passing a *copy* of the local variables `x` and `y`, as arguments to the parameters of the same name. The names being identical doesn't matter; these are still distinct memory locations.

Inside your `swap` function, you are correctly exchanging these `x` and `y` parameters, but as you see, that doesn't do anything to the values in the calling function. You've only edited those local copies, which cease to exist at the ending `}`. To persist this change, you need your swapping to work with the "original" `x` and `y` local variables from `main`, and *not* these temporary copies of them.

To fix this, you need to pass *the address of* `x` and `y`. The addresses will be copied, but the position they point to will remain the same. You can then exchange the values at those addresses.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y) {
    int temp = *x; // Read out of location x, copy it into a local `temp`.
    *x = *y; // Read out of location y, and write to location y.
    *y = temp; // Read out of the local `temp`, and write it to location `x`.
}

int main(void) {
    int x, y;
    printf("Enter X: \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter Y: \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    // Pass the addresses of `x` and `y`, causing the addresses to be
    // copied, rather than the values themselves.
    swap(&x, &y);

    printf("%d, %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re “completely unrelated”: “Being a copy of” is a relationship. You may know what you mean, but you have to communicate it to people who do not, and that means using words correctly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point. How about "completely distinct"? Do you have any suggestions? Feel free to edit.

Comment: "completely different variables despite the similar names"

Answer (score 0):

C variables are passed by value - a copy is made. You are swapping the copies and the original variables are unchanged. You have to use **pointers** to the original (and pointer syntax) to be able to change their values from inside a function.

```
void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int temp;
    temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}

int main(void){
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter X: \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("Enter Y: \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    swap(&x,&y);

    printf("%d , %d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: I'm afraid an unexplained code snippet like this would be of low educational value to a poster, who is clearly a student.

Comment: @enzo I am on my phone and was building up the answer in multiple edits, feeling a need to "save" my work and also get in before it was answered by someone else.

Comment: @Alexander I am on my phone and was building up the answer in multiple edits, feeling a need to "save" my work and also get in before it was answered by someone else,

Comment: @Scooter Fair enough!

Comment: Note that there is no need to separately declare and initialize `temp`.

Comment: @Alexander It's not fair. Do not sugarcoat it.

Comment: @Chris True. But I want to change a minimum amount of his code and the other answer has it that way